# How can i efficiently speed-up Canvas redraws in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm studing from scratch HTML5 Canvas object, so the purpose of this question is merely about improving knowledge.

You can live try see my project on:

https://github.com/ISDesign-tv/Canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/IvanSollima/T6YKL/

The target is:

> Find a way to improve Canvas speedness by clearing and drawing just
>   the portions of the canvas area that need to be updated.

The Background:

> Every thing you can draw is a polygon, and its tracked as an object.
>   Every object has properties, including vertex positions, lines, boundingbox, centroids
>   etc.

My approach:

When i need to delete, drag, or update somehow an object, 
I pass the target object to a functionn called **refresh(poly, callback);**

**refresh()** has the optional arguments sPoly and callback.

When its called with both parameters, the function looks for intersections of bounding boxes of existing objects with the passed one, and then returns an array of objects that needs to be refreshed.

Then it passes the resulting vector (**toWipe**), to the clear function, that actually cleares the area of each object boundingbox.

Then it passes the vector again to the draw function, that draws the objects back.

Finally it runs the callback;

PIECE OF CODE:

```
//sPoly is the object representing the actual polygon drawn on screen
refresh: function (sPoly, callback){
        var toWipe;

        //callback is optional
        callback = callback || function () {};

        //if you passed sPoly in the function call refresh() will
        //try to clear just the area of the Canvas that need to be update instead of 
        //clearing everything

        if(sPoly){
            //getBBoxIntersect takes an object, and a tolerance value, and returns an
            //array of objects that will need to be redrawn as consequence of the 
            //redraw of the passed object.

            toWipe = getBBoxIntersect(sPoly, 5);

            //clear all the object in the array toWipe based on each one bounding box.
            self.clear(toWipe);

            //draw again that objects
            self.draw(toWipe);
        }else{
            self.clearAll();
            self.draw(polys);
        }

        callback();

    },
```

The problem is that the clear function doesn't  actually clear the object bounding box before the redraw, but after.
You can easily repeat the bug while you drag object with fast mouse movements.

Is there a way to improve my approach?

How to repeat the bug:

[image: Two polys showing their center and bounding boxes]

Two polys showing their center and bounding boxes

[image: The dragged poly shows in gray the areas that javascript actually rewrote, and a bunch of errors, where it seems that javascript did not wrote]

The screen shows in gray the areas that javascript actually rewrote while dragging, and a bunch of errors, where it did not.

[image: You can see that when the first object approaches the second, javascript update also the region of the square]

You can see that when the triangle approaches the square, the refresh function also update the region surrounding the square

Comment: Clear the whole screen, and re-draw everything on each frame. You'll be at 60 fps very easily. You did bet on the wrong horse.

Comment: Your problem is that you think about translation like it was a smooth move, while it's more like a "teleport" from one frame to the next frame. You have to clear and re-draw two areas : the one where the object was before moving, and the one where the object will be after moving. Your code is very long, so it's hard to help you with the implementation.

Comment: @GameAlchemist that's only true for good hardware, most of the internet users (aka most of the world) don't have access to a dev/gaming pc (most don't even own a pc) , and since js has a bit of a performance problem to begin with I like this direction :)

Comment: @sebcap26 Good point, i understand that is difficult to relate to my specific code, as its long, the strange "and buggy thing" if you ask me, is this:

Comment: My intent in the refresh function is to clear the triangle bounding box in the first place, and just after run the callback() that should update triangle positioning.

So that's what i wrote

 $(this).on("mousemove.drag", function (e) {
    //omitting non essentials [..]
    self.refresh(triangle, (function () {
       //updateObject positioning
    });

This function should first clear the triangle and after redraw it elsewhere!

Comment: @Winchestro : The fact that js is slow inclines to have canvas 'compute' overlaps and such for you. your reasoning could only apply for a *very* complex scene (>5000 objects) , when redrawing all would be costly. But then, computing what needs redraw becomes very costly. And also there's a huge -and thought stopping imho- issue about this post : talking about performances with no benchmark and no target platform. 'speed-up'... as compared to what ? Ivan is going in the wrong direction, redrawing all is both simpler and faster in 99% cases, including this one.

Comment: **Clearing the canvas** Clearing the entire canvas is actually much faster than calculating which areas of the canvas are dirty and clearing just those areas.  That's because clearing the entire canvas only involves setting every element in canvas's pixel array to zero.  Zero-filling an array is blazingly fast.

Comment: **Redrawing all shapes**  Even on the slowest of devices Html Canvas is more than fast enough to redraw dozens of primitive paths within the refresh cycle.  That's what canvas is designed to do.  A dirty little secret(!): even if you attempt to clear/redraw a portion of the canvas the browser will likely clear/redraw the entire canvas anyway.

Comment: **An experiment in performance**  Most of your clearing/redraws occurs when you are "dragging" the selected shape.  A useful learning exercise would be to layer 2 canvases on top of each other.  Draw your shapes on the bottom layer, but when the user selects a shape then (1) redraw the bottom canvas without the selected shape (2) draw and drag the selected shape on the top layer and (3) when the user is done dragging, draw the top canvas to the bottom canvas with bottomContext.drawImage(topCanvas,0,0) and clear the top canvas.

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll go for the simplest approach then, as you suggested, and i'll let you know what i will discover when the scene will become more complex. 

@markE - thanks for the tips!

Comment: I would go with what @markE said and just create a new canvas for each poly and layer them.

Comment: @powerc9000.  Just 2 canvases total.  The bottom canvas holds all unchanging shapes and the top canvas displays just the shape being dragged.  After dragging, the top canvas shape is drawn to the bottom canvas [with bottomCtx.drawImage(topCanvas,0,0)] and the top canvas is erased. ;-)  Cheers!